# google calendar api asp.net c# delete event

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have this function

```
 private static void DeleteEvent(CalendarService service, string pTitle,DateTime pDate)
    {
        FeedQuery query = new FeedQuery();
        query.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full");
        AtomFeed calFeed = service.Query(query);
        foreach (AtomEntry entry in calFeed.Entries)
        {
            if (pTitle.Equals(entry.Title.Text))
            {
                entry.Delete(); break;
            }
        }
    }
```

how i can delete a event by title and date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These might help:

http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#DeletingEvents
http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#RetrievingEvents

I'd guess something like the following might work:

```
EventQuery query = new EventQuery("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full");  
query.StartDate = ...;
query.EndDate = ...;
EventFeed feed = service.Query(query);
foreach (var entry in feed.Entries)
{
    if (pTitle.Equals(entry.Title.Text))
    {
        entry.Delete(); break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the above solution will work but I would suggest another approach. Instead of traversing all the events every time and deleting if found, why not ask Google to find the specific event for you. It can be done by using `ExtendedProperty` using the approach below

1. Assign an ID (same as you set in your DB) to each event you add.
2. When deleting you pass the ID to delete and use Query to fetch it for you
3. Delete the specific event

---

```
Google.GData.Calendar.EventEntry Entry = new Google.GData.Calendar.EventEntry();

//create the ExtendedProperty and add the EventID in the new event object, 
//so it can be deleted / updated later
ExtendedProperty oExtendedProperty = new ExtendedProperty();
oExtendedProperty.Name = "EventID";
oExtendedProperty.Value = GoogleAppointmentObj.EventID;
Entry.ExtensionElements.Add(oExtendedProperty);

string ThisFeedUri = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/" + CalendarID 
+ "/private/full";
Uri postUri = new Uri(ThisFeedUri);

//create an event query object and attach the EventID to it in Extraparameters
EventQuery Query = new EventQuery(ThisFeedUri);
Query.ExtraParameters = "extq=[EventID:" + GoogleAppointmentObj.EventID + "]";
Query.Uri = postUri;

//Find the event with the specific ID
EventFeed calFeed = CalService.Query(Query);

//if search contains result then delete
if (calFeed != null && calFeed.Entries.Count > 0)
{
   foreach (EventEntry SearchedEntry in calFeed.Entries)
   {
      SearchedEntry.Delete();
      break;
   }

}
```